# Bright flash using capacitor and LED?

Tags: led, capacitor, flash, light

I'm looking to produce an intensely bright single flash exceeding 2000 lumens for half a second. If I hook a charged 10,000uF electrolytic capacitor up to a 100w LED chip, will it work and how bright will it be? Is there a better way of doing this electronically?

Comment: You may need to define "intensely bright," the duration of the "flash," and specify the 100 W LED chip's "action integral of a pulse" (specified as \$I^2\cdot t\$, or Joules per Ohm, and identifying when the LED will melt or fuse itself from the pulse of energy.)

Comment: If 2000 lumens are distributed to an area of one square meter, the result is an intensity of 2000 Lux. Full sunlight is about 100,000 Lux, 50 times more. You should think about your definition of "intensely bright".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a super bright flash there is no better way than using a high voltage Xenon discharge. In other words, and electronic camera flash. LEDs will not give you anywhere the near the same peak power.

Your setup might get you a peak power of ten times rated continuous power, that is around 1kW peak, but a camera flash can be in the hundreds of kilowats. [There is a good wikipedia article on the techniques used.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(photography))

If you want the ultimate, there is a banned weapon called the isotropic radiator, which uses high explosive to pump a compressed Noble gas like Xenon. Anyone looking at it at night would probably get eye damage even from humdreds of meters distance

Comment: Aren't those usually just a few milliseconds long? Half a second is a rather long time for a flash.

Comment: Actually, Xenon strobes murdered the flash bulb business.  Trouble is, old school flashbulbs (the ones the size of regular light bulbs) had a duration of a significant fraction of a second.  Xenon strobes, having such short duration, did not put out nearly the light.  This killed off the wondrous art of "painting with light" such as seen in O. Winston Link's photographs. So wanting to surge a 100W LED for 500ms is a very reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

---

You can find the brightness you can get in the LED chip datasheet (or on the site where you bought it). It should be in lumens. For the 100w LED you can get ~8000-14000lm.

This project could be helpful - https://www.instructables.com/id/100w-LED-Flashlight-1/

Answer (score 3):

> If I hook a charged 10,000uF electrolytic capacitor up to a 100w LED chip, will it work and how bright will it be?

No, it won't work, assuming with "hook up" you simply mean "connect". You'll either violently burn your LED the moment you connect it, or you'll be driving it significantly below its maximum brightness.

LEDs are constant current devices, and half a second is rather long in terms of electrons and heat. Capacitors have an exponential declining discharge rate. Exponential != constant.

So, what you need is a constant current supply that is on for half a second. Where its energy comes from is of secondary interest, could be a battery, the power grid or a supercap.

Find the maximum operating current from the datasheet. Feel free to add a bit (that current is probably rated for continuous operation, but you'll probably let the LED cool down after that half second. A good cooling solution is a must, here!). Also find the expected forward voltage at that current.

You'll need a constant-current supply that can go at least up to that voltage. Which, in the context of supercaps and 100W LEDs might imply it's going to be a step-up converter. Now, stepping up 100W is a nontrivial task, but it's definitely something one can design based on application notes.

The control scheme of said step-up converter should either include a current limit, or be based on the current flowing through the LED. There's dedicated LED drivers that are designed to do that, but most boost converter architectures simply use a reference voltage as feedback – in constant voltage mode, that reference voltage would be derived from the output voltage by a resistive divider, but here, we want constant current, so we'd derive it from the voltage over a low-side shunt resistor.

Control the step-up converter with anything. Probably a microcontroller, turning it on for half a second.

How bright it'll be obviously depends on your LED, which I don't have the datasheet for. Generally, with modern LEDs, 100W is a lot, and you'd be very well-advised to take precautions not to look into the beam, and keep easily flammable materia (paper!) at a sufficient distance from the LED. Don't touch the LED. It **will** get very hot (ask the scars on my right thumb and index finger).